# Undefined Reference to cv::Tracker::update

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, linker-errors

I am trying to use the tracking API of OpenCV. I did make of OpenCV by following the instructions here:https://github.com/itseez/opencv_contrib/. On building I had to turn off a few parameters in CMake gui. After make, I ran the following code using Tracking API:

```
#include <opencv2/core/utility.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/tracking.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <tracker.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

static Mat image;
static Rect2d boundingBox;
static bool paused;
static bool selectObject = false;
static bool startSelection = false;

static void onMouse( int event, int x, int y, int, void* )
{
  if( !selectObject )
  {
    switch ( event )
    {
      case EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        //set origin of the bounding box
        startSelection = true;
        boundingBox.x = x;
        boundingBox.y = y;
        boundingBox.width = boundingBox.height = 0;
        break;
      case EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        //sei with and height of the bounding box
        boundingBox.width = std::abs( x - boundingBox.x );
        boundingBox.height = std::abs( y - boundingBox.y );
        paused = false;
        selectObject = true;
        break;
      case EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:

        if( startSelection && !selectObject )
        {
          //draw the bounding box
          Mat currentFrame;
          image.copyTo( currentFrame );
          rectangle( currentFrame, Point((int) boundingBox.x, (int)boundingBox.y ), Point( x, y ), Scalar( 255, 0, 0 ), 2, 1 );
          imshow( "Tracking API", currentFrame );
        }
        break;
    }
  }
}

//
//  Hot keys:
//   q - quit the program
//   p - pause video
//

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    //open the capture
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    if( !cap.isOpened() )
    {
      return -1;
    }

    //
    //  "MIL", "BOOSTING", "MEDIANFLOW", "TLD"
    //
    string tracker_algorithm = "MIL";
    if ( argc>1 ) tracker_algorithm = argv[1];

    Mat frame;
    paused = false;
    namedWindow( "Tracking API", 0 );
    setMouseCallback( "Tracking API", onMouse, 0 );

    Ptr<Tracker> tracker = Tracker::create( tracker_algorithm );
    if( tracker == NULL )
    {
        cout << "***Error in the instantiation of the tracker...***\n";
        return -1;
    }

    //get the first frame
    cap >> frame;
    frame.copyTo( image );
    imshow( "Tracking API", image );

    bool initialized = false;
    int frameCounter = 0;

    for ( ;; )
    {
        char c = (char) waitKey( 2 );
        if( c == 'q' || c == 27 )
            break;
        if( c == 'p' )
            paused = !paused;

        if ( !paused )
        {
            cap >> frame;
            if(frame.empty())
            {
                break;
            }
            frame.copyTo( image );

            if( selectObject )
            {
                if( !initialized )
                {
                    //initializes the tracker
                    if( !tracker->init( frame, boundingBox ) )
                    {
                    cout << "***Could not initialize tracker...***\n";
                    return -1;
                    }
                    initialized = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //updates the tracker
                    if( tracker->update( frame, boundingBox ) )
                    {
                        rectangle( image, boundingBox, Scalar( 255, 0, 0 ), 2, 1 );
                    }
                }
            }
            imshow( "Tracking API", image );
            frameCounter++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However I am getting an error that the class Tracker's functions are not defined, on linking. Here is part of my build log:

> g++.exe -LC:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib -o bin\Debug\main_project.exe obj\Debug\t1.o   C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_bgsegm300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_bioinspired300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_calib3d300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_ccalib300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_core300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_dnn300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_dpm300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_face300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_features2d300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_flann300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_fuzzy300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_hal300.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_highgui300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_imgcodecs300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_imgproc300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_ml300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_objdetect300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_photo300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_plot300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_reg300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_rgbd300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_saliency300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_shape300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_stereo300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_stitching300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_structured_light300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_superres300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_surface_matching300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_text300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_ts300.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_video300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_videoio300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_videostab300.dll.a C:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_xobjdetect300.dll.a
>   obj\Debug\t1.o: In function `main':
>   E:/main_proj/main_project/t1.cpp:79: undefined reference to`cv::Tracker::create(cv::String const&)'
>   E:/main_proj/main_project/t1.cpp:116: undefined reference to `cv::Tracker::init(cv::Mat const&, cv::Rect_<double> const&)'
>   E:/main_proj/main_project/t1.cpp:126: undefined reference to`cv::Tracker::update(cv::Mat const&, cv::Rect_&)'

I suppose it is some problem that arose during make of OpenCV. Can Somebody suggest a solution?

Comment: Your program does not see contibution library (with `tracker` module). 1) Did you use `-lopencv_contrib` ? (do you compile with IDE?  what linker flags line does it use then?) 2) What problem you have met on `opencv` compilation? Maybe, `opencv` contribution modules had not been built? 3) what parameters did you turn off in CMake?

Comment: -lopencv_tracking300

Comment: @John_West What I have posted is the log of the linking process with g++. As you suggested opencv contrib modules have not been built as I do not observe a library file with that name in my lib/ directory. What do you think could have gone wrong during make?

Comment: @berak The specified library file is missing in my lib/ directory

Comment: From what the two of you have suggested, I guess something had gone wrong in the way I used Cmake. I do not exactly recollect which all parameters I had to turn off. But those had to be done as the make process resulted in errors otherwise. For example see this make error that was solved by turning off "BUILD_opencv_line_descriptor" as mentioned: http://answers.opencv.org/question/62312/detection-of-planar-objects/. Can you please suggest a workaround to this problem?

Comment: I remember I had to turn off these flags: "BUILD_opencv_xfeatures2d", "BUILD_opencv_aruco" and "BUILD_opencv_ximgproc" in CMake GUI as the make process resulted in errors otherwise.

Comment: try to build again, i'm sure something went wrong with the tracking module

Comment: @berak Anyway I will have to disable the above mentioned flags in CMake, otherwise it won't build. Are they the problem?

Comment: no, that's unrelated (imho). if you look at the modules/tracking/cmakelists.txt, you see the dependacies. (btw, make sure, cmake -DBUILD_opencv_tracking=ON is set)

Comment: Try to rebuild, e.g. if your build failed with error on `tracking`, then you fixed something, and it has built (apparently), the module still could have compiled wrong way with missed parts. Use `make clean`

Comment: @John_West I need to clear cache of Cmake and try all over again right?

Comment: Yes, I think :) **"If something gone wrong - recompile it"**

Comment: `-lopencv_tracking` worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebuilt the entire set of modules and now it works. I am still not sure what exactly went missing earlier. You need to experiment quite a few times before you can arrive at a successful build. Thanks a lot for the suggestions- @berak and @John

Answer (score 0):

When linking with `-L` (path to directory with library) option like

```
-LC:\opencv\min_bin\install\x64\mingw\lib
```

you should use `-l` as well to link to specific library.

it seems that `-lopencv_tracking300` library is not found.